# Problems with SCNetworkReachability functions when host has both IPv6 and IPv4 addresses

Tags: objective-c, ios, macos, ipv6, reachability

I have written a network client for iOS which uses the `SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName()` function to initiate monitoring of the availability of the remote hosts.  This works beautifully if the remote hosts have only IPv4 addresses or only IPv6 addresses.

A problem arises when the client is on an IPv4 only network and is monitoring a host which has both an IPv4 address and an IPv6 address.  The client will monitor the IPv6 address of the remote host and indicate that the host is unavailable even though the IPv4 address is reachable.

I've searched and have been unable to find a way to instruct SCNetworkReachability to default to monitoring the IPv4 address if an IPv6 network is unavailable.

I can work around this by programmatically determining the public IP addresses of the device, manually resolving the hostname, and using the IPv4 address if a non-link local IPv6 address exists, however I'm hoping that someone has a simpler solution.

Since the functions are the same for both iOS and OS X, this problem would affect OS X clients as well.

My specific implementation is the .m and .h files for my BKNetworkReachability class:
https://github.com/bindle/BindleKit/tree/master/BindleKit/controllers

Comment: did you have any luck with this in determining network type/family without having to look at the ip addresses?

Comment: I would think that a portable solution might be to monitor both ipv4 and ipv6 forms of the address.  Then encapsulate some logic to differentiate between them if one/both fires change events.